# Typescript prevent generalization of string literal to type

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

So I have this constant Object

```
const STUDY_TAGS ={
  InstanceAvailability: { tag: "00080056", type: "optional", vr: "string" },
  ModalitiesinStudy: { tag: "00080061", type: "required", vr: "string" },
  ReferringPhysiciansName: { tag: "00080090", type: "required", vr: "string" },
  NumberofStudyRelatedSeries: {
    tag: "00201206",
    type: "required",
    vr: "number",
  }
};
```

Now I want to infere the return type of each object based on its vr value, but if I look at typeof STUDY_TAGS all key-value pairs look the same like this:

```
 InstanceAvailability: {
        tag: string;
        type: string;
        vr: string;
    };
```

Can I somehow force typescript to keep the string literals instead of generalizing them to the type string?
I thought of defining the Object with the type Record<string, {tag: string, type: string, vr: "string" | "number"}> but then the all I get when looking at typeof STUDY_TAGS is

```
Record<string, {
    tag: string;
    type: string;
    vr: "string" | "number";
}
```

I am really lost here and have no idea on how to solve this problem. Shouldnt it somehow be possible to infer the return type based on an Object having one of 2 string values?
In the end I want to create a function which takes in the object and know the returned type based on the vr value

```
function doSomething<Type extends "number" | "string">({tag, type, vr} : {tag : string, type : string, vr: Type}) : Type extends "number" ? number : string
{
 if(vr === "string") return "test";
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe function overloading and narrowing could help you. Here's a simplified example:

```
function doSomething(vr: 'string'): string
function doSomething(vr: 'number'): number
function doSomething(vr: string): string | number {
  if(vr === 'string) return 'Test!';
  return 0;
}
```

Then, when you call `doSomething`, TypeScript's typing system can infer the return type, because you told it whenever `vr` is equal to `'string'`, the function returns a string, and whenever `vr` is equal to `'number'`, the function returns a number.

```
const foo = doSomething('string'); // TypeScript knows 'foo' is a string
const bar = doSomething(2); // TypeScript know 'bar' is a number
```

[Here is a more complete example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAysCuATEAVAhgcwEJoM7QF4oBvAKCgqmEwC4pdgAnASwDsMAaKcy0SOhi3ZdSAX1J9ocIRjhJUmKETnJ02PNABkJKADdGdAOSC2GQ1HGSoAOXgBbAEYRGKhRiWwEqzDnxRtxHoGUIas9k6M5uIS4FJebh62js6ualAAPp4yqZgA3KSkAMYA9qwMsCgAqgAiAJoA%20igAggDiMB5kFACSZdSshRBNumjMADZoDmPMoHSB1Bh0AEQADKsAHKsArABsi1ySS8VgwMylaKN7QUsm7IsWHDwAssWI59PMELhsrrNUtFArdarbYARkuBwBjAgAEd4MwoYhLvprkxTHdRA8KAAlCAAM2cMgACgALEBfQrMNBlaxoOwQX7zJarZYbZYATmW4NiSyhsPhEERXGRAJuGHRmJs4WcxVxrhx42AApgzg%20uFmPAojIBqwATMsQXrdhLNdzITC4Qi9hqrgCwslGFaKOJRPlSLj4P0TqUoIhijBinTgMTTAAKYjzfaxIWMURQOjSUw5DAASjj9FR7DdHsKXtYPr9AYgQdD4cwkcg0djdCSESTqbodoiWc9pzzvv9geD7DDEaoUaCVc88jUyYbUsYGXTMlInWYuJD%20iUBCIi1Fi1TUIQjDzi0VDEW%20Sgm-g26gy3y0RKvSguOKxQ87cLxe7Oi1hgNAGZDOX6SFJN%20bVCccomTXIoAAenAm87ygZhcCgNAoEbZwilKcoHDQCciEfTtQ1ff53x1L8fyMf9oyMUUQLAyCoAwic4IQqdTFIIA) with your specific use-case on TypeScript's playground.

Answer (score 0):

My main problem was not getting the type info from the object because it would generalize my string constants to the general type string although I defined my object with `Object.freeze()`. The solution was to define the object like so:

```
const obj = {a: {test: "hi"}} as const;
```

Comment: This is almost more of a comment than an answer and it looks almost the same as @Tom 's answer. I realize new users can't comment but it would be polite to accept/upvote his answer instead of posting a sort of commenty answer.

Comment: I wrote the answer before tom wrote the comment, thats why I did not choose his answer. Otherwise his comment would have been exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Then it would appropriate to upvote his answer -- it exactly solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to declare the types 'as const'

```
const STUDY_TAGS ={
  InstanceAvailability: { tag: "00080056", type: "optional" as const, vr: "string" },
  ModalitiesinStudy: { tag: "00080061", type: "required" as const, vr: "string" },
  ReferringPhysiciansName: { tag: "00080090", type: "required" as const, vr: "string" },
  NumberofStudyRelatedSeries: {
    tag: "00201206",
    type: "required" as const,
    vr: "number",
  }
};
```

Above I've just added the 'as const' for the `type` property so you can see the difference. You can add these to any of the properties above to get the exact values rather than their primitive.